# Change Listfragments selected item from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, android-fragmentactivity

i implemented a master/detail flow layout in my app.
There is a fragment activity, a listfragment and a fragment.

In my fragment i have a prev/next button to navigate in the listsfragments items, so i dont have to scroll and click to another, its for the phone view, but i want this to work on tablet too.

Here is a pic of my [layout](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1MJ70by139YoLU1DcteJmICX1tC2LhC_1u2iNNwMQSr8/edit?usp=sharing).

If i click on prev or next, the detailfragment changes its content to the next or prev item, but on the left the selected item wont change.
So the question how to tell the left fragment to change the selection?

I used this sample:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i had a solution, i used this code to get it work.

```
ListFragment lf = (ListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.list_fragment);     
        slf.getListView().setItemChecked(mCurrentPosition, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you want to change the item selected on the ListFragment when clicking a button on the fragment.

To my mind, the best way to do this is to send a message to the activity (for example onPrevButtonClicked() see [Communicating with activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) ) and then in your activity you can find the fragment with something like `Fragment fragment = (Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);` and then call a method on your ListFragment which will select the item on your list.

Comment: Yes, i updated the question with a picture. But the onclick listener is in the fragments oncrieteview. So i just dont know how to communicate back.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your link helped a lot, i dont know how a couldnt see that on developers page :D